# Google calendar update using Zend

Tags: zend-framework, gdata

I would like to update an event in Google calender using Zend Gdata.
Right now i have added the event to a particular calendar using php. While editing I would like to update this to a different calendar which i have permisson. So that the entry must be deleted from original calendar and should be added to  the new calendar. How can i do this using Zend data with out triggering a call to delete the event while updating

Answer (score 0):

Here is some great stuff from IBM using the zend frame work to get you going.  Does basic Editing, https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-googleclndr/

Other variables include `$description`, and where which is in an array.

```
$event->where = array($gcal->newWhere($where));
```